# How to apply Neumann boundary conditions in Newton's method

Tags: finite-element, finite-difference, ode, boundary-conditions

Suppose that I have a very long and tedious set of differential equations. After discretization, I can get a mapping $f:\mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}^N$ such that solutions $\phi =(\phi_0,...,\phi_{N-1})$ to the discretized diffferential equations are exactly the zeros of $f$, i.e., $f(\phi)=0$.

Now say I want to find solutions $\phi$ which satisfy some Neumann boundary equation, e.g.,
$$
\frac{\phi_1-\phi_0}{dx}=1
$$
Of course, I can always define another function
$$
F(\phi)= \left(\frac{\phi_1-\phi_0}{dx} -1, f(\phi) \right):\mathbb{R}^{N} \to\mathbb{R}^{N+1}
$$
And just use Newton's method on $F(\phi)$. However, since the derivative/Jacobian $DF$ is not a square matrix in this case, things are a little more complicated. Is there an easy way to modify Newton's method to incorporate Neumann conditions?

Indeed, in this [post](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/14812/do-i-need-to-impose-boundary-conditions-in-the-jacobian-matrix), the OP  deals with Dirichlet boundary conditions, e.g., $\phi_0=0$,, by removing row $0$ of the Jacobian $Df$ and replacing it with the Jacobian of $\phi \mapsto \phi_0$, which is just the Dirac delta at $0$, i.e., $(Df)_{0j} \mapsto \delta_{0j}$. This way the "modified" Jacobian is a still a square matrix. However, this doesn't seem to work if I were to replace row $0$ of $Df$ with the Jacobian of $\phi \mapsto (\phi_1-\phi_0)-dx$, i.e., $(Df)_{0j}\mapsto \delta_{1j}-\delta_{0j}$.

I have also read posts, e.g., [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/12913/poisson-equation-with-neumann-boundary-conditions), where they substitute the Neumann boundary condition into the differential equation. However, since my $f$ mapping is quite long and tedious (and not just a simple second order derivative), this would be a little cumbersome for me to do by hand.

Are there any simple alternatives to applying Neumann boundary conditions?

**EDIIT**. Actually, I realized there was a typo in my code. My initial method works.

Comment: shall we close this question?